# User authentication with yt gem and devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to setup the yt gem using the guide here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yt/frames#Web_apps_that_require_user_interactions (scenario 3), but I am kind of lost. I don't really have a general idea even. I'm new to this whole "omniauth" thing and the YouTube tutorials I've watched (rails casts and stuk.io) haven't been very helpful. If anyone could point me in the right direction for user authentication with this gem (with devise maybe?), that'd be great!

Comment: What have you tried already? What exactly are you stuck on? Please include your code in the post, and any issues/errors you have encountered.

Comment: Like I said, I have no idea where to start, I've added the code in the documentation, but beyond that, I'm lost

Comment: You can not just ask ' I want to built a Time Machine so tell me where to start and what is the procedure. Google about YT gem, Omniauth, Devise and start building you app and then if you stuck anywhere share your piece of code with information on what have you done, what are you trying and where are you currently stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

`Devise` along the `Omniauth` is good, but `yt gem` wont recognise the `client_id` and `client_secret`. `Omniauth gem` will work along with `yt gem`.

**Step 1**

Add `google-oauth2 gem` and `yt gem` in your gem file

**Step 2**

In your `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'Google-Client-id', 'google-secret-key', scope: 'go through scopes in [google-omniauth github page][1]'
end
```

**Step 3**

Add yt gem functionality wherever needed. For example, if you want to upload video to youtube add the below snippet in your video.rb.

```
def upload!(user)
    account = Yt::Account.new access_token: user.token
    account.upload_video self.file, title: self.title, description: self.description
  end
```

and in your videos_controller.rb

```
def create
    @video = Video.create(title: params[:video][:title], description: params[:video][:description], file: params[:video][:file].try(:tempfile).try(:to_path))
    @video.user_id = current_user.id
    if @video.save
      uploaded_video = @video.upload!(current_user)
    end
end
```